# paste and get the values of respective variable

Tags: r

I am trying to get value from eval parsing but i am not getting the value instead getting the error message as `Error in file(filename, "r") : cannot open the connection`. How do i dynamically pass and get the value. Please help

```
ab_cc_dd = 55.4
gm = "ab"
```

Code:
`df <- data.frame(gm, eval(parse(paste(gm,"_","cc_dd",sep=''))))`

Expected output

```
>df

ab  55.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need `get` instead of `eval(parse`

```
data.frame(col1 = gm,col2 = get(paste0(gm,"_cc_dd")))
#   col1 col2
#1   ab 55.4
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
tibble(col1 = gm, col2 = !! rlang::sym(str_c(gm, "_cc_dd")))
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#  col1   col2
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1 ab     55.4
```

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter for `parse` is `file`. So it's looking for file of that name. You want to pass your argument to `text`:

`df <- data.frame(gm, eval(parse(text = paste(gm,"_","cc_dd",sep=''))))`